# MongoDB+PHP. Как в трех документах выбрать нужное поле за один запрос?

Tags: php, mongodb

Есть коллекция с документами, в каждом документе есть поле-массив, документ я нахожу по полю 'key', затем выбираю в каждом найденном документе поле-массив 'obyav', с целью потом объединить эти массивы. Делаю я это вот так примитивно:

```
$dok1 = $collection->findOne(array('key' => $key1));
$dok2 = $collection->findOne(array('key' => $key2));
$dok3 = $collection->findOne(array('key' => $key3));
$mas1 = $dok1['obyav'];
$mas2 = $dok2['obyav'];
$mas3 = $dok3['obyav'];
```

Получается три запроса к Mongo, можно это сделать как то за один запрос или более красиво. Чтоб на выходе у меня был объединенный массив из $mas1 $mas2 $mas3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Решение

Да, есть возможность выбрать данные одним запросом, используйте `.find` (не `.findOne`) и оператор [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/in/). Скрестив документацию и ваши названия полей, получим:

```
{key: {$in: [key1, key2, ... keyN ]}}
```

Результат будет - массив документов с перечисленными значениями `key`

При переводе в PHP получится что-то веселое, вроде:

```
array('key'=>array('$in'=>array(key1, key2, ... keyN)))
```

### P.S:

1. Результат - массив документов превратите в массив полей с помощью `array_map`.
2. Используйте аргумент [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/#definition) при поиске документов. Это позволит вам выбирать из базы только нужные поля.